# Resource-Based Policies in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, rbac

I found that Azure RBAC Role Assignment is the equivalent of AWS Identity-Based Policies, where I can assign roles to a user, a group or a service principle. But what is the Azure equivalent of AWS Resource-Based Policies? How can i assign roles to a resource?

For example if I want to give a Function permission to read from SQL DB , or to a scheduled job a permission to read Blob Storage contents and create a new Cosmos DB document. How can I do it Azure?

Is that was service principal came for? But service principal is only for web applications.

Comment: "But what is the Azure equivalent of AWS Resource-Based Policies? How can i assign roles to a resource?" - unfortunately, there is no equivalent. You can't set it up so that only role X has access to resource Y. You can do other things - like create managed identities and grant them access - but it's far more convoluted than what you have in AWS.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [Managed Identities for Azure Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) for that. They would be the Azure analogue for that.

Also, literally any application can use service principal authentication, not just web applications